# Javascript access TR from TD

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table row, and within that, I have a td (whatever it stands for). I would like to change the class attribute of the TR my TD is in without using an ID or a name. Like that:

```
<tr>
    <td onclick="[TR].setAttribute('class', 'newName')">My TD</td>
</tr>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: It's amazing how many answers have gone straight for jQuery (despite this being the *simplest possible* thing to do even in plain old DOM), and then still got the syntax wrong!

Comment: That's because the answer has been changed after some questions were given.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`td` stands for table data..

now .. in your case you need the `parentNode` property of the `td` ..

```
<tr>
<td onclick="this.parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'newName')">My TD</td>
</tr>
```

or as bobince suggested in his comment

```
<td onclick="this.parentNode.className= 'newName'">My TD</td>
```

Comment: +1 for solving problem with out using ID (like requested in question) or relying on Jquery

Comment: PERFECT!
table data... I see. Thank you!

Comment: `setAttribute('class')` doesn't work right in IE6-7. There are many attributes where IE gets it wrong: avoid `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` in HTML documents for this reason. Instead, use DOM Level 1 HTML properties: `this.parentNode.className= 'newName'` is more compatible and more readable.

Comment: thanks for that one. I daresay I find it extremely annoying how IE simply overrides the standards. ^^

Comment: @arik-so — this isn't overriding the standards, it is a simple bug. It is fixed in IE8.

Answer (score 14):

In jquery, it would be really simple if you have the reference to your td:

```
$(this).closest('tr');
```

If you really don't want to take a dependency on jQuery, then you could just do a loop getting the parentNode and checking it's type as a more general purpose solution. In this case you could just get the parentNode since tr is always a direct parent of td. You can do something like this (note this was not tested):

```
var parent = myTd.parentNode;
while(true) {
  if(parent == null) {
    return;
  }
  if(parent.nodeName === "TR") {
    return parent;
  }
  parent = parent.parentNode;
}
```

Comment: you realise that if you have the HTML  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> then all of those <td> share the same parent, they are not nested under each other. They are siblings.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the answer to note that mine is a more general purpose script.

Comment: Should be parent.nodeName === "TR" rather than parent.nodeName = "TD"

Comment: `tagName`/`nodeName` comparisons should always be case-insensitive (ie. `nodeName.toLowerCase()==='tr'`), you shouldn't rely on browsers changing the case. I'm not really sure what the point of looking up the ancestor list is when you've got a `<td>`: its direct parent will always be the `<tr>`.

Comment: I was thinking more from the point of where you click on a link in a td or something. You typically aren't actually clicking on the td itself. And FWIW, nodeName is always all capitals so doing toLowerCase is redundant.

Comment: @bobince Whilst the HTML spec may or may not say that a TD should only be bested with in a TR it may not always be the case. I have played with trying to get a table body to scroll, and that involved nesting the TD with in a DIV. It's unlikely, but may happen.

Comment: @thecoshman: It doesn't happen. The browser ‘fixes’ the table up for you so that `<td>` is inside `<tr>` is inside `<tbody>`, regardless of what your input was. Different browsers may apply different fixes for invalid input (which is why you shouldn't rely on it), but alert the `innerHTML` and you will see the proper expected nesting.

Comment: Isn't `closest()` also valid plain JS? e.g. `onblur="myFunction(this.closest('tr'));"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the dom element in javascript, you can use .parentNode() which will give you the parent node, which should be the table row. Then you can set .className

Comment: in javascript it's just:  **document.getElementById("someTDitem").parentNode.style.background = '#77dd77';**

Comment: What? OP wanted to set the *class* not some part of the style.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery it could be something like this

```
$("yourtdselector").closest("tr").attr("class","classname");
```

For your code

```
<tr>
    <td onclick="changeClass(this,'classname')">My TD</td>
</tr>

function changeClass(elem, class)
{
    elem.parentNode.className = class;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) is probably the easiest way of doing this, you can use selectors such as:

```
$('table.mytable tr').addClass('red');
```

To add a class of 'red' to all tr's in table.mytable.  That's just the tip of the iceberg - check it out it should do what you need.

Comment: That is not actually answering the question at all. You basically just told him to go look up how to use jQuery. Not useful at all.

Answer (score -3):

Without any extra framework:

```
document.getElementById("theTableName").rows[1].cells[1].className = "someclassname";
```

Comment: That's not getting it based on a td.